# Boundness of a continuous function $u: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, functions, inequality, continuity

I can't understand why if I have a function $u: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, continuous.

(Maybe $u$ should be defined on $\overline{\Omega}$, tell me then please).

And if $\exists$ M $\gt 0$ s.t $u(x) \lt$ M, $\forall$ x $\in \Omega$,

then we can say that, and by **continuity** of $u$:

$u(x) \lt$ M,
$\forall$ x $\in \overline{\Omega}$ (i.e on $\partial{\Omega}$, also).

Can I have some help please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding your second line - yes, $u$ would need to be defined on $\overline \Omega$ for you to speak of $u(x)$ for any $x \in \overline \Omega$

Comment: Anyhow, this seems straightforward if you use the characterization of closures as sequence limits, i.e. $y \in \overline \Omega$ if $\exists \{y_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ a sequence such that $y_n \to y$. Approach it by contradiction then, i.e. suppose $\exists x \in \overline \Omega$ such that $u(x) \ge M$. What would this mean? See what you can do with that, I think it leads somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is slightly incomplete. If $u(x) < M$ for all $x \in \Omega$ then $u(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in \overline{\Omega}$. Because it could be that $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact and $M = \displaystyle\max_{x \in \overline{\Omega}} u(x)$.

To demostrate this, note that for $ x \in \overline{\Omega}$ there is a sequence $(x_n) \subset \Omega$ such that $ x_n \longrightarrow x$ then by continuity $u (x_n) \longrightarrow u(x)$. And remember that if given a sequence $ (y_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $ C $ a real number such that $y_n \leq C$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n \leq C$. So take $y_n = u(x_n)$ and $c = M$ and you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your statement is incorrect. Consider $\Omega = (0, 1)$ and $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x$. Then take $M = 1$. We see that $\overline{\Omega} = [0, 1]$, and $f(1) = 1 = M$.

The correct conclusion is that if we have $u : \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $u(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in \Omega$, then $u(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in \overline{\Omega}$.

To do this, we recall that $\overline{\Omega}$ is the smallest closed set containing $\Omega$. Then consider $V = \{x \in \overline{\Omega} | u(x) \leq M\} = u^{-1}([M, \infty))$.

Because $V$ is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map, $V$ is closed. And it's easy to see that for all $x \in \Omega$, we have $x \in V$. Then $\Omega \subseteq V$. Then $\overline{\Omega} \subseteq V$, since $\overline{\Omega}$ is the smallest closed set containing $\Omega$. Then for all $x \in \overline{\Omega}$, $u(x) \leq M$.

Comment: But maybe we would suggest that $u \lt M$ on $\Omega$, implies $u \le M$ on $\overline{\Omega}$! Isn't it? (i.e without considering $u \le M$ on $\Omega$).

Comment: @sara If $u < M$ on $\Omega$, then $u \leq M$ on $\Omega$. And we have just shown this implies $u \leq M$ on $\overline{\Omega}$. We just get a slightly more general result by talking about $u \leq M$ on $\Omega$.

Comment: sorry but when you said: If $u < M$ on $\Omega$, then $u \leq M$ on $\Omega$. Is this because if in general $a \lt b$, then $a \le b$? Because if $a<b$ is true, then ofcourse $a \le b$ is true, isn't it? Or by continuity of $u$ you said that?